# java.security.AccessControlException in Tomcat with DISABLED SecurityManager

Tags: tomcat, derby, securitymanager, accesscontrolexception

I have a web application written in Java using Apache Derby database in Tomcat 7. The exception will not occur on every call to the web application, but only after about 5 to 10 successful requests.

This is what happens (from my log):

> The exception 'java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect")' was thrown while evaluating an expression.

I run Tomcat 7 with Java 1.8.0_45 and the included Apache Derby Database. The exception occurs. Below is the exception.

> at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

Tomcat is running with disabled SecurityManager, so i expect no java.security exceptions at all.

Any ideas why this happens and what i can do about it?

Comment: Make sure you are getting the *complete* information: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: And include the full information from your derby.log.

Comment: Did you try to change the Connector in server.xml from `Nio2` to `Nio`?